# Does Elasticsearch version 5.1.1 or later support the LIRE plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Does Elasticsearch version 5.0 or later support the LIRE plugin?
If support LIRE plugin, how to install LIRE plugin?(in ubuntu)
I try to two way, and get error messages:

Running:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install com.github.kzwang/elasticsearch-image/1.2.0
```

I've the error below:

```
ERROR: Unknown plugin com.github.kzwang/elasticsearch-image/1.2.0
```

Running:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://github.com/kzwang/elasticsearch-image.git
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: 'elasticsearch' directory is missing in the plugin zip
```

How do I install the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this plugin has not been updated for 2.x and 5.x.

https://github.com/kzwang/elasticsearch-image/issues/19

IMO it would be better to rewrite this as an ingest plugin for elasticsearch. Would be a great addition IMO.

But to answer to your question, I don't think you can find an easy workaround for now.

Comment: Can you tell me if you know how to index and search images using ElasticSearch??